# The meaning of "to pack in"

Tags: word-meaning

What is the meaning of "to pack in" in the following sentence?

> And so, week after week, he packed in the columns of the Liberator
>   facts, the most damning facts, against slaveholders, their cruelty and
>   tyranny.

Comment: The preposition ***in*** refers to the *Liberator* (presumably a newspaper). He stuffed / crammed damning facts about slavery into his newspaper column (perhaps an op-ed piece he wrote for the paper on a weekly basis). The cited example isn't very "fluent", since in many other contexts ***to pack in*** is effectively a "phrasal verb" - which makes this usage awkward to parse even for a native speaker.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That would have been more clear if it had been written  "... he packed the facts in the columns of the Liberator..." However, I can understand now.

Comment: I just checked, and I see now [it's a C19 text](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5mSqwPUlAdYC&q=%22he+packed+in+the+columns+of+the+Liberator+facts%22&dq=%22he+packed+in+the+columns+of+the+Liberator+facts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivwaSAsvTdAhWTa8AKHSfkDMQQ6AEILzAB). It was perfectly acceptable back when it was written, but it would be considered at the very least "stylistically weak" today. (So don't beat yourself up just because you found it difficult to parse! :)

Comment: Please always provide a link, author and/or historical context. Otherwise, it becomes a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

The verb is not "pack in" here, but simply "pack".  **in** is part of a prepositional phrase.

It is not uncommon to find the verb separated from its direct object by a prepositional phrase, especially when, as here, the direct object phrase is a long or so-called "heavy" one:

> And so, week after week, he packed
>   in the columns of the Liberator
>   facts, the most damning facts, against slaveholders, their cruelty and tyranny.

Some writers would consider the alternative an infelicity  and a potential cause for confusion and loss of clarity:

> And so, week after week, he packed
>   facts, the most damning facts, against slaveholders, their cruelty and tyranny
>   in the columns of the Liberator.

Another possibility is to simplify the object phrase and then tack a  phrase onto the end of the sentence:

> And so, week after week, he packed
>   the most damning facts against slaveholders
>   in the columns of the Liberator
>   facts showing their cruelty and tyranny.

Answer (score 0):

[[...]he packed the most damning facts into the columns of the Liberator, facts against slaveholders, their cruelty and tyranny.

That would be how it would be edited today.

to pack facts in or into the columns of a newspaper. pack here means put in a lot of facts.

The idea is that columns can only take a certain amount of text, and he put a lot of facts into the space he had to fill as a journalist.